# Make only one part of a string bold in vuejs

Tags: string, vue.js

I have a string of text that contains a number. I just wanted to make the number bold, not the rest of the text. is there an easy way to make this possible in vue js?

```
  <a :href="detailUrl">
    {{ content }}
    <span v-if="detailText && detailUrl" class="notification-detail-link"
      >{{ detailText }} >></span
    >
  </a>
```

The content variable comes in as a prop. This variable contains the string of text with a number that I would like to make bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed property `textBoldNumbers` based on your prop the use `v-html` directive to render it :

```
props:["detailText "],

computed:{
  textBoldNumbers(){
      return this.detailText.replace(/([0-9])/g, "<b>$1</b>")
   }
}
```

template :

```
 <a :href="detailUrl">
    {{ content }}
    <span v-if="detailText && detailUrl" 
    class="notification-detail-link"
    v-html="textBoldNumbers"
     > </span
    >
  </a>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      detailText: "aaa 98 vvv ddd 7 98"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    textBoldNumbers() {
      return this.detailText.replace(/([0-9])/g, "<b>$1</b>")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <span v-html="textBoldNumbers"> </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not about the detailtext variable. It is about the content variable, this variable contains a number that I would like to have bold. It is above it

Comment: just replace `this.detailText` by `this.content` then `<span v-html="textBoldNumbers"></span>` instead of  `{{content}}`